# Spring JpaRepository doesn't delete row in table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-one

I'm using postgresql and have 2 classes.
User:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="usr") //
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

And Post

```java
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;
}
```

When I try to delete post by id Hibernate set all fields in null except user_id and not deleting. I've tried adding `@Query` in PostRepository

```java
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM post WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteById(long postId);
```

Tried adding `@OneToMany` in User. Tried different FetchType, but nothing helps.

PostRepository:

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

Delete post like this:

```java
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public String blogPostDelete(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    postRepository.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/blog";
}
```

I'm almost shure there's something wrong in @ManyToOne but can't understand what exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `@Transactional` annotation above your custom query. 
 If result still will be the same you can find something in my working code.
Deleting was working: 
Parent:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class EntityUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid_user", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=EntityNote.class, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<EntityNote> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And child:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
public class EntityNote {
   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid_note", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
   
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner")
    private EntityUser owner;
}
```

You can try to do similar relation and check it will works and remodel for your requirements.

Comment: Did you use postrges? I've made like this (except id) and result is the same, may be you have some application.properties or pom dependencies that i missed

Comment: Yes, I've used postgres. This is my `application.properties` without username, password and host URL.
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`
`server.error.include-message = always`

Comment: Have you tried to add transnational to your custom query?

Comment: And you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323401/deleting-entity-in-spring-jpa?rq=1

Comment: Tried @Transactional, not helping :(

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried to write in the `Post` and `User` similar fields and annotations like in my code? I don't see any other ways :/

Comment: You`ve added a comment with your service to another answer. You have transactional in class Service but have you tried to put it in interface Repository?

Comment: I've tried to put it into interface too, but still not working :c

Comment: But have you implemented anototions like in code in my answer? `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@JoinCollumn`, `@Collumn`. May my configuration will allow you to delete because it works for me.

Comment: I've created new project with entities like yours and it deletes, but `@DeleteMapping` doesn't work now and I delete with using `@PostMapping` and still don't understand why it doesn't work in my project

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try to fetch the record first using the 'id'

```
Post post = postRepository.findById(id)
```

then use the return Post object and call delete. No need to create such native query, JpaRepository (CrudRepository) has the basic built in functions you need

```
postRepository.delete(post)
```

Comment: Added 
Post post = postRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if(post!=null)
            postRepository.delete(post);
but result is the same

Comment: Did you try adding @Transactional?

Comment: Yes, same result

Answer (score 0):

When working with Hibernate, it is interesting to put objects in session, whenever you want to perform any operation.

So, try load you User object and remove the post with user.getListofPosts().remove(post.getId()).

After that, update your user object.

This should be done within your operation annotated with @Transactional.